# TypeScript で Google Feed API を利用したい

Tags: javascript

TypeScript にて Google Feed API を利用したいのですが、以下の一文だけでエラーになってしまいます。

```
var feed = new google.feeds.feed(); // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

型定義ファイルには`google.feed.api.d.ts`を利用しています。

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/google.feeds/google.feed.api.d.ts

何か不足しているものがあるのか、大きな勘違いをしているのか、教えていただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

※改めて回答し直します

こちらでも現象を確認できました。
おそらく型定義ファイルが誤っている(?)からではないでしょうか。

- 誤
  `new google.feeds.feed();`
- 正
  `new google.feeds.Feed();`

https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide#feed

とりあえず対応するのであれば、`google.feed.api.d.ts`の`feed`クラスを`Feed`に書き換えてしまうのが簡単だと思います。

Comment: ご指摘の通り`Feed`と書き直してみたところ正常に動きました。元APIと違って小文字になっている点は確かに気になっていたのですが、本当にその部分がいけなかったのですね。

明らかな誤りだと思いますが、NuGetでの公開ではすでに5回マイナーアップデートされており、ダウンロードも918回行われているようです。
この修正をpull requestするべきなのか悩ましいですね…。

Comment: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/3382
mergeして頂けました。

Comment: TomoyaShibata @vvakame お疲れ様です！